# Getting the content type in Template.php

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I am trying to get the content type to conditionally add JavaScript code/files to the template.

The code in template.php is the following one:

```
echo $node->type;
```

The same line in "node.tpl.php" is returning the content type. How do I get it to work
in template.php?

Comment: In which function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put `hook_preprocess_node()` in your template.php.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'your_type') {
    //Add the JavaScript file.
    drupal_add_js('/path/to/jsfile.js')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The "template.php" file for a theme is the equivalent of a ".module" file for a module: It's a collection of functions that are invoked from Drupal in specific cases.

As you are referring to the "node.tpl.php" file, I guess you are adding a preprocess function in your theme. In that case, the variable to use inside `THEMENAME_preprocess_node()` is `$variables['node']`, which is the same variable available in `THEMENAME_preprocess_page()`.